# Финский флаг в HTML

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать финский флаг с помощью HTML?

Comment:  - https://emojipedia.org/flag-for-finland/, но у меня не отрисовывается, получается надпись `FI`

Answer (score 9):

Википедия показывает такую схему:

[image: схема флага]

Поэтому, если я нигде не просчитался, получается так:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, antiquewhite, silver);
  padding: 1em 32%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 61.111%;
}

div {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 27.778%, #005498 27.778%, #005498 44.444%, transparent 44.444%), 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 36.364%, #005498 36.364%, #005498 63.636%, transparent 63.636%)
    white
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: мне нужно  было именно таблицами ))
пока чтот не понимаю, текст ваш вставляяу в редактор и не получается

Comment: @alex, про таблицы в вопросе не сказано. Переделай селектор с div'а на какой-нибудь класс (и не забудь его на div поставить). Не может не получаться, потому что тут всё работает - сам же видишь в сниппете. И обрати внимание, что перед `white` нет запятой.

Comment: ладно парни не запаривайтесь я просто туплю ))) начинающий, про таблицы забыл сказать  извените (( ещё раз большое вам спасибо

Answer (score 6):

Есть множество вариантов. Можно и SVG сделать, можно картинку PNG.. Но можно и табличкой:

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 180px;
}

td.lt {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
}

td.ct {
  background-color: #003580;
  width: 30px;
}

td.rt {
  width: 100px;
}

td.cc {
  background-color: #003580;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="lt">
    </td>
    <td class="ct">
    </td>
    <td class="rt">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="cc">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="lt">
    </td>
    <td class="ct">
    </td>
    <td class="rt">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Это не очень хороший вариант, конечно. Профессионал бы меня раскритиковал, то бишь это не грамотное решение. Советую *покопать* в интернете SVG - хорошая вещь для реализации таких задач.

Comment: у меня не получается сделать горизонтальную линую ((((

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <!-- See on html algus -->
<head>

<style>
tabel, th, td { border: 
1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse; }
</style>
<title> Lehe pealkiri </title>
</head>

<body> 

<table frame="box" height="210" width="330" cellspacing"0">
<caption>Soome lipp</caption>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="white" height="80" width="5"></td>
<td bgcolor="#003366" height="60" width="3"></td>
<td bgcolor="white" height="80" width="5"></td>
</tr>

Comment: @alex, атрибут `colspan` помогает реализовать так называемую *горизонтальную линию* на финском флаге. Я в коде это написал, посмотрите, как это устроено. Если непонятно, то теория http://htmlbook.ru/html/td/colspan в помощь.

Comment: спасибо большое буду разбираться, хорошо, 4то есть люди, которые готовы помочь. )

Comment: 21 век на дворе, когда же вы про эти таблицы забутите...

Comment: задание дали в школе (((

Comment: @Air, что не так с таблицами?

Comment: @Grundy, ничего осбенного...  Просто не люблю их....))))  Пахнут нафталином...)))

Answer (score 4):

Сложный вариант)
Суть в том, что тут всё пропорционально, думаю понятно как и что)

```css
/*
Из вики узнал о размерах флага и т.п.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Флаг_Финляндии
*/
.flag {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 110px;
  background: #003580;
  position: relative;
}

.flag::before, .flag::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 solid #fff;
}

.flag::before {
  width: calc((100%/18)*5);
  border-top-width: calc((110px/11)*4);
  border-bottom-width: calc((110px/11)*4);
  left: 0;
}

.flag::after {
  width: calc((100%/18)*10);
  border-top-width: calc((110px/11)*4);
  border-bottom-width: calc((110px/11)*4);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flag-finland {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.flag-finland:before,
.flag-finland:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #003584;
}

.flag-finland:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}

.flag-finland:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag-finland"></div>
```